# How to stop get user media that used with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, getusermedia

I'm using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)` with Redux but I am not able to find a way to stop media stream.

I've tried to stop media stream in reducer and action

In reducer, I tried that

```js
case actionTypes.GET_USER_MEDIA_CLOSE:
    return {
        ...state,
        stream: {
             ...state.stream,
             active: false
        }
    };
```

Also in reducer,

```js
export const getUserMediaClose = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let track = getState().videoCall.stream.getTracks()[0];
        track.stop();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to stop user camera stream with Redux?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change

```
export const getUserMediaClose = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let track = getState().videoCall.stream.getTracks()[0];
        track.stop();
    }
}
```

To

```
export const getUserMediaClose = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        getState().videoCall.stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        getState().videoCall.stream = undefined;
    }
}
```

Difficult to know without seeing more code (e.g. how are you storing the stream object, is there n stream objects or just 1?). There may be a case where you have a reference to a different stream object which is not being stored correctly. To debug this I would create a window.streams array where each time you you make a new stream I would push it to this array (perhaps with a timestamp or some unique ID) to make sure you only have one, and this one stream is the same as the one in your store. You can debug this via the console by entering "window.streams" and you can inspect the object.